# Failed to install Hubot on Heroku

Tags: heroku, hubot

I can't install my Hubot on Heroku and have no idea. I tried several versions of node and npm but always get the same error:

[heroku error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubzf5.png)

I tried that to install the dependencies "moment" and "express" but  i get the error:

[npm express error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjNsz.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line with `version` in your package.json is quoted incorrectly - a starts with `"` but is closed with `'`.

Can you add a bit of your package.json file? 
I assume it fails locally in the same manner?